# Join two collections in mongodb with same key value include in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections as

**collection1** :

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("5a5e62dae4b0189610784ca9"),
  name:"project1",
  "cause":[{
            indications : [{
                            pattern: "(.*Failed to read artifact)"
                          }]
          }]
}
```

**collection2**:

```
{
 _id : ObjectId("58229558e4b05d3853a6a501"),
 "categories" : [
              "CompilationFailure"
                ],
 "indications" : [
        {
            "pattern" : "(.*Failed to read artifact)"
        }],

}
```

The result that I want to get is :

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("5a5e62dae4b0189610784ca9"),
  name:"project1",
  "categories" : [
          "CompilationFailure"
            ],
  "cause":[{
            indications : [{
                            pattern: "(.*Failed to read artifact)"
                          }]
          }]
}
```

Can I join two collections via **pattern** key? I tried it with $lookup syntax but it failed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

That should get you going:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').aggregate({
    $lookup:
     {
       from: "collection2",
       localField: "cause.indications.pattern",
       foreignField: "indications.pattern",
       as: "categories"
     }
}, {
    $addFields: { // transform into desired structure
        "categories": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$categories.categories", 0 ] } // select the first value only to get rid of the nested array, not sure if that works for all your records/cases...
    }
})
```